# kerl --with-wx doesn't create wxe_driver.so

Tags: erlang, wxwidgets, kerl

`kerl --with-wx` doesn't create an erlang installation with wxe_driver.so. Should it? I'm trying to make an erlang build that will run observe, but still get:

```
ERROR: Could not find 'wxe_driver.so' in: /home/don/erlangs/17.4/lib/wx-1.3.2/priv
```

.kerlrc contains:

```
KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--with-wx"
```

Comment: You sould look for build process messages. May be you just don't have WX development libraries required to build driver

Comment: @Lol4t0 - Why wouldn't the build just fail, then?

Comment: I rememer getting build with `crypto` not working without ssl dev libraries instead of build fail, and may be it works the same for WX. I'm not sure but just check it.

Comment: So, the file config.log was rich with errors. :) One that looked relevant indicated that glu.h could not be found. So, based on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=395396&p=2365634#post2365634 I ran sudo apt-get install build-essential libsdl1.2debian libsdl1.2-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev, which was probably overkill, but now I have a glu.h, and wx is working in erl.

Comment: @Lol4t0 - Thanks. If you want to turn our chat into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang build procedure just skips some optional components build steps if build host system does not have all the required dependencies to build that components, even configure (or kerl) was told to make build with that components included

If you find yourself in a situation where Erlang, that was built from source, blames some module could not be loaded, you should check if it was built

### In this particular case

Look for errors in a file named `config.log` under ~/.kerl. It should indicate what's missing.

To build `wxe_driver` you should have WX development libraries installed on your system. You have to refer to your system documentation to learn how to install them. In this case, since glu.h was missing, running `sudo apt-get install build-essential libsdl1.2debian libsdl1.2-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev` added the missing file.

Comment: As I'm setting this up on another box, I'm finding that I also needed to install libwxgtk-media2.8-dev. It appears that there's no need for the extra config in .kerlrc. Kerl will build with wx by default if all the dependencies are in place.